# What should be the correct path of jar file in persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence.xml

I have a jar file and persitence.xml in META-INF in that jar file. I want to configure the persistence.xml with `<jar-file>`. Also I have a lib directory on the same folder with jar file. But I am not able find correct path for `<jar-file>` tag. I tried;

```
<jar-file>lib/entity.jar</jar-file>
<jar-file>../lib/entity.jar</jar-file>
<jar-file>./lib/entity.jar</jar-file>
<jar-file>../../lib/entity.jar</jar-file>
```

but no luck. Entity manager can not find the entities in entity.jar

Comment: "When using jar-file, you must specify a path relative to the jar file the persistence.xml file is in".

Comment: so, I can not do that for jar file ?

Comment: Your first try, `<jar-file>lib/entity.jar</jar-file>`, should have worked.  Are these .jar files deployed together in an .ear file or a .war file?

Comment: not ear nor war. I have only jar and it reads necessary  dependencies from lib folder. Everything works except hibernate doesn't see entity.jar.

Answer (score 0):

As it's stated in the JPA 2.2 specification (see section **8.2.1.6.3 Jar Files**):

> One or more JAR files may be specified using the jar-file elements instead of, or in addition to the mapping files specified in the mapping-file elements. If specified, these JAR files will be searched for managed persistence classes, and any mapping metadata annotations found on them will be processed, or they will be mapped using the mapping annotation defaults defined by this specification. *Such JAR files are specified relative to the directory or jar file that contains[91] the root of the persistence unit.[92]*
>
> ...
>
> *[91] This semantics applies to persistence.xml files written to the persistence_2_0.xsd or later schema. Due to ambiguity in the Java
> Persistence 1.0 specification, provider-specific interpretation of the relative references used by this element may apply to earlier versions.*
>
> [92] Persistence providers are encouraged to support this syntax for use in Java SE environments.

Your case looks like the **Example 1** from the specification:

```
app.ear
   lib/earEntities.jar
   earRootPUnit.jar (with META-INF/persistence.xml )

persistence.xml contains: <jar-file>lib/earEntities.jar</jar-file>
```

But if you use JPA 1.0 it looks like you should check related part of the provider-specific documentation.